# Switch Statment doesn't work properly with multiple conditions on Case

Tags: php, switch-statement

```
$letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']; 
$x = (1==1 || 2==2);
$y = (3==3 || 4==4);
$z = (5==5);

foreach ($letters as $key => $letter) {
        switch ($letter) {
            case 'a':
                echo "a";
                    break;
            case 'b':
                echo "b";
                    break;
            case 'c':
                echo "c";
                    break;
            case 'd':
                echo "d";
                    break;
            case 'e':
                echo "e";
                    break;
            case 'f':
                echo "f";
                    break;
            case 'g' && ($z || $y):
                echo "g";
                    break;
            case 'h' && ($x):
                echo "h";
                    break;
        }
}
```

I don't know why but at the last two cases the **'g'** and **'h'** It doesn't work properly and gets a double **'g'**, The result i expect is

**abcdefgh** but i keep getting **abcdefgg**, What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `case 'g' && ($z || $y):`wont work

Comment: What's the point of `$x = (1==1 || 2==2)`?

Comment: `switch ($foo): case 'bar':` translates to `if ($foo == 'bar')`... It should be obvious why case 'g' doesn't work then.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Just an example of the original code. Both this and the original or any values gives the same value.

Comment: Well, if it's not required to demonstrate anything, then leave those things out! You are supposed to provide a minimal example to keep the quality of the questions here up, and adding distractors doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your code, the `g` case will always evaluate to `true`:

```
var_dump('g' && ((5==5) || (3==3 || 4==4))); // true
```

`switch` cases use loose comparison and when `$letter` is `g` it will be evaluated with `true`.  Since `g` is loosley `true` it will execute that case:

```
var_dump('g' == true);  // true
var_dump('g' == false); // false
```

You probably need this:

```
        case 'g':
            if(($z || $y)) { echo "g"; }
                break;
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be intuitive to try and assume switch will spit out boolean values, and you can then append additional boolean logic to your cases. This is wrong, however.

From the PHP docs on switch:

> This is how it works: First we have a single expression n (most often
>   a variable), that is evaluated once. The value of the expression is
>   then compared with the values for each case in the structure.

Each of your cases needs to exactly match the evaluated `$letter$ expression, you cannot have additional boolean expressions and whatever else in the cases.

Comment: I thought `switch($a) case $b && ($c || $d):` works as `if ($a && ($c || $d))`

Comment: certainly not. what you just posted is not logically sound, either.